# How to multithread a program and return results to main.py?

Tags: python, multithreading, speech-recognition, wait, vosk

I am using Windows and python. The objective is simple, running the `main.py` starts a speech recognition and once it recognizes what was said returns the text to `main.py`. The speech recognition program recognizes without any issues, the problem is at multithreading and getting the result back to `main.py`.

Here is the main.py:

```
import threading
from speechEngine.recognize import *
from SpeechSynthesis.speech import *
from core.AI import *
spch= "default"
newthread=threading.Thread(target=speechrec())
newthread.start()
while(True):
    if(spch == "default"):
        print("at default")
        continue
    else:
        print(spch)
        result=process(spch)
        speak(result)
        spch="default"
```

And here is speech recognition which is called as a new thread:

```
import argparse
import os
import queue
from typing import Text
import sounddevice as sd
import vosk
import sys
import json
#from vosk import SetLogLevel
#SetLogLevel(-1)
def speechrec():
    q = queue.Queue()
    "a lot of argument lines have been deleted to increase readability"

    try:
        if args.model is None:
            args.model = "model"
        if args.samplerate is None:
            device_info = sd.query_devices(args.device, 'input')
            args.samplerate = int(device_info['default_samplerate'])

            model = vosk.Model(args.model)
            with sd.RawInputStream(samplerate=args.samplerate, blocksize = 8000, device=args.device, dtype='int16', channels=1, callback=callback):
                rec = vosk.KaldiRecognizer(model, args.samplerate)
                while True:
                    data = q.get()
                    if rec.AcceptWaveform(data):
                        vc=rec.FinalResult()   #produces raw output of what the user said
                        vc=json.loads(vc)
                        vc=vc['text']    #converts the user speech to text format
                        if vc != '':
                            global spch
                            spch = vc          
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        parser.exit(0)
```

Comment: Most Python implementations have a [Global Interpreter Lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock), so you should consider using some other programming language, or designing your software architecture with several communicating processes

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch  Is there any way  I can run the recognition and get the result back?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I dont think thats his issue at all in this case ... to send back to the main thread use a queue and put messages in it from the thread and pull them out from the main thread

Comment: You may need to use operating system specific inter-process communication primitives. For Linux, see [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), [pipe(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html), [poll(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Can u give me a code example on how to do it with the queue.. I just need the text back at main.py. I am using windows

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I am relatively new to coding and i really wanna make this work . its for a project work

Comment: Be aware that it takes [ten years to learn programming](http://www.norvig.com/21-days.html), so you need to allocate efforts and time to your project. Consider following university courses and going inside libraries to read books

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch how to use a queue, at main.py and get result, thats the only part i need

Comment: Benji: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation. That said, there are numerous question having to do with subject of using queues here.

Comment: `Thread` needs function's name without `()` - `Thread(target=speechrec)` - and later it will use `()` to run this function. At this moment you run `speechrec()` in main thread and it should block all code -like `result = speechrec()` `Thread(target=result)`. And if you want to use queue then create it in main thread and send to thread `q = queue.Queue()` `Thread(target=speechrec, args=(q,))` - creating it inside `speechrec()` is useless.

Comment: @furas thank u bro I will try that..

Comment: @furas it worked but it doesnt not return the value to main.py (spch)

Comment: you have to use `queue` for this - in `speechrec` use `q.put(...)` and in main `q.get()`. OR assign value to global variable - threads share global variables - and then you don't need `queue`. And I don't understand why you use `data = q.get()` in `speechrec` if you don't send any values to `speechrec` - and this `q.get()` may wait for value on queue and block all thread.